# Who decides the required reputation for privileges?

Tags: discussion, reputation, privileges

Is the required reputation for [privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) subject to change over time, maybe looking at statistics on the data of the user base?

Who decides and manages these levels?

Could it be managed by very high-reputation users?

Did it already happen to change in the past?

If it changes, what happens to the users who already have privileges, are they updated?

Comment: The white male behind the scenes (yes, it's a white male) who decides these things asked to remain anonymous. All we know is that during what is referred to as "the incident" he was told to "check his privilege", which we all assume he may have misinterpreted.

Comment: @Bart is that the person people commonly refer to as "The Man"? That would explain so much.

Comment: I'm uncertain @Pekka웃. I know he has a lot of stuff stuck to him. While many seem to take pride in that, at this point I feel it might qualify as bullying.

Comment: @Bart The founder of stackexchange? The person whom we all worship?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is the required reputation for privileges subject to change over time, maybe looking at statistics on the data of the user base?

Yes, possibly. I'm not sure whether privileges have ever been subject to retroactive changes but other parts of the system sure have, like the amount of reputation awarded to upvotes on questions.

> Who decides and manages these levels?

Some of the many women, men, and... cacti? that make up [The Man](https://stackoverflow.com/company/leadership) around here.

> Could it be managed by very high-reputation users?

Not currently, no. It's probably not going to happen, either: historically, these kinds of decisions are not left to the user base.

> Did it already happen to change in the past?

I don't know of an instance where it did, although it might have happened.

> If it changes, what happens to the users who already have privileges, are they updated?

Judging from current behaviour (when you lose rep and fall below a privilege level, you lose it again) I would speculate that the code's natural inclination at the moment would be that privileges would be re-calculated across the board.

Whether that'll be what happens if and when such a change ever happens, will depend on how important they deem that one or the other be the case, I suppose.